# Pinia state not remains prototype

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, prototype, nuxtjs3, pinia

I using nuxt3 + pinia (as docs recommend). When user login I create a Client object then update that Client by using pinia actions. The point is that Client object's prototypes are removed. I tried add it to localstorage but the result is sill the same. Any advice for this case? Thank you very much.

clientStore.ts

```
"useClient",
state: () => {
  client: {} as ClientType
},

actions: {
  updateClient(clt: ClientType){
      this.client = clt
   }
}
```

login.service.ts

```
//import createClient ...

const newClient = createClient.login({email, password})
```

> client has prototype

```
(1) const clientStore = useClient.updateClient(newClient)
(2) localStorage.setItem("client", JSON.stringify(newClient))
```

---

```
const client1 = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem("client")!) 
const client2 = useClient.client
```

> client1 and client2 has lost their prototypes

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . "Prototype" term has a specific meaning in JS, nothing that is listed in the question suggests that it's applicable.

Comment: @EstusFlask sorry for ambiguous infor, I mean the Client object has other methods served as prototypes, like this pic bellow the question (I've just updated)

Comment: You're describing this as something ordinary for a store, but it's not. It's unclear why you expect a prototype to be there, why this is important and at which point it disappears. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .